# Ros building CMake workspace

Tags: c++, cmake, ros

I'am trying to build a simulation environment by using `gazebo` and `ROS` and I'm facing with the problem bellow with CMake. I have tried to understand what the problem it is - a lost dependence or is there a missing package, but this didn't lead me to the correct solution. Please help.

**Build output:**

```
ImportError: "from catkin_pkg.package import parse_package" failed: No module named 'catkin_pkg'
Make sure that you have installed "catkin_pkg", it is up to date and on the PYTHONPATH.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/usr/bin/python3
  "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py"
  "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml"
  "/home/evadro/catkin_ws/build/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake")
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:74 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:168 (_catkin_package_xml)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:56 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/evadro/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/evadro/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

Comment: Did you actually check if you have the `catkin_pkg` module installed? On Ubuntu use `sudo apt-get install python-catkin-pkg`. For other distros use `pip`.

Comment: yeah the catkin_pkg is exist put do you know how can i check if it is at added in the same paython path could this be the problem

Comment: If you follow the instructions on setting up your catkin workspace (official ROS documentation), it should work. The question is: did you do that?

Comment: i did follow the instructions

Comment: Could it be that you have a Python mismatch version? Run `which python`, then `python -V` and finally `dpkg -L python-catkin-pkg`.

Comment: i did that but the same error, i think that the python version that in the file are python 3 and in their it is looking for catkin -pkg but the package is in the version python 2.7  do you know how by using command line to shift between the two version or how can i make the file search in the 2.7 file  thank you

Comment: CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/usr/bin/python3
  "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py"
  "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml"
  "/home/evadro/catkin_ws/build/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake")
  returned error code 1

Comment: Last time I checked ROS is still holding onto Python 2.7.

Comment: yeah i know but see" /usr/bin/python3" thats why i thought that it is looking in the wrong path

Comment: i am using Ubuntu 16.04 and i am new to the system

Comment: It is. I think that something went wrong during the installation but don't know what exactly.

Comment: ####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/evadro/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.5.2", minimum required is "2") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python3 "                                                     do anyone know how can i change the python version from 3 to 2.7?

Comment: Did you build ROS yourself or did you install it from the Ubuntu repo? Btw you should also add which version of ROS you have in your question.

Comment: i build it by myself from source the ROS (kinetic)

Comment: Aha. This is the problem then. When you run CMake to configure your catkin_pkg you have given the wrong Python interpreter. You need to reconfigure and rebuild. This issue probably affects other packages as well. Do let me know to post this as the answer. Next time you should start with "I build it from source". ;)

Comment: thank you i will try it and let you know

Comment: sorry i tried to do it but i think iam missing some points how do i rebuild it and reconfigure it should i delete it then re-install the cmake  again can you please tell me the steps i am sorry but i am new to ros and ubuntu so iam kind of lost here thank you

Comment: The problem is not with cmake. Just delete your build directory, re-create it, go inside, run cmake with your configuration (perhaps cmake-gui would be better for you since it has a user interface that you can interact with) and then build. This is the safest way to make sure that no garbage is left from a previous configuration of the build process.

Comment: I already deleted my build directory and re-create it but it shows the same error again :(

Comment: You need to point to the right Python. I'm not familiar with the variable in the CMakeLists.txt that you need to change but it probably contains 'PYTHON' in it. I had a very similar issue when I was building OpenCV 3 2 years or so ago. I didn't check for the value of that variable and it messed up my whole build.